# How to I use ssh2_auth_pubkey_file with ppk file?

Tags: php, ssh, public-key

I have a .ppk file and converted it to .pem file with PuTTYgen.

```
$connection = ssh2_connect($bastion_ip, $bastion_port, array('hostkey'=>'ssh-rsa'));
if (ssh2_auth_pubkey_file($connection,'user_name','public_key','private_key')) 
{
  echo "Authentication Successful!";
}
else
{
  echo('Authentication Failed...');
}
```

As I know, I can use the .pem file as `public_key`... and what should I have to put the `private_key`?
Should I make another private key file from .ppk file?

Answer (score 0):

The `.pem` file goes to `privkeyfile` argument.

What goes to `pubkeyfile` argument is a file that contains the public key in a format like this:

> ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAA....NX6sqSnHA8= rsa-key-20121110

You can see that in PuTTYgen, after you load your key file.